# Argument types problem ('float', 'const int') in array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, math, compiler-errors, pine-script

I've been trying my first codes in pine script. The question is this. I have created few array.new_float to use as buffers in the 'for' statement. The thing is that I need to do some math over the data. Now, once the 'for' is done, an error pops: 'Cannot call 'operator -' with argument 'expr0' = 'High'.An argument of 'float[]' type was used but a 'const int' is expected'.

Please, if anyone knows what am I doing wrong, I will thank you.

Edit: I will leave the script of what I'm trying to do here

```
//@version=5
// Indicator name
indicator("DAF_Swing_Index", shorttitle= 'DAF_SwInd', overlay=false)
// Input
T = input.int(30000, title = 'Ratio de escala', minval = 1000, maxval = 150000)
Shift = input.int(0, title = 'Desplazamiento horizontal', minval = 0, maxval = 100)

// Array
SWINGINDEX = array.new_float(200)
Open = array.new_float(200)
Open1 = array.new_float(200)
Close = array.new_float(200)
Close1 = array.new_float(200)
High = array.new_float(200)
Low = array.new_float(200)

// Other variable
var float SwingIndex = 0
var int StartBars = 1
Prev_calculated = bar_index
Rates_total = bar_index + 1
var float SH1 = 0
var float SI = 0
var float R = 0

// Initial bar verification
if Rates_total < StartBars 
    SwingIndex := 0

Primero = 1
if Prev_calculated > Rates_total or Prev_calculated <= 0
    Primero := 1
else
    Primero := Prev_calculated-1

// Main process
for bar = Primero to Rates_total
    array.push(Open, high[bar])
    array.push(Open1, open[bar-1])
    array.push(Close, close[bar])
    array.push(Close1, close[bar-1])
    array.push(High, high[bar])
    array.push(Low, low[bar])

    K = math.max(math.abs(High - Close1), math.abs(Low - Close1))
    TR = math.max(math.max(math.abs(High-Close1), math.abs(Low-Close1)), math.abs(High-Low))
    
    ER = 0.0
    
    if Close1 > High
        ER := math.abs(High - Close1)
    if Close1 < Low
        ER := math.abs(Low - Close1)
    
    
    SH1 := math.abs(Close1 - Open1)
    R := TR - 0.5 * ER + 0.25 * SH1
    SI := 0.0
    if R != 0
        SI := 50 * ((Close - Close1) + 0.5 * (Close - Open1)) * (K / T) / R
    
    SwingIndex := SI
// ploting result

plot(SwingIndex, title = 'Swing Index', style = plot.style_line,  color = color.rgb(193, 255, 51, 10))
```

Comment: Please do not upload a screenshot of your code. Instead, copy and paste your code here and use the code sample `{}` button to format your code.

Comment: Can you share your whole code or a minimum repruducible code?

Comment: @BarisYakut I have added the script just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what the error message tells you is, your are passing an array, where it expects a const value.

Like here:

```
K = math.max(math.abs(High - Close1), math.abs(Low - Close1))
```

All those variables (`High`, `Close1`, `Low`) are arrays. It simply can not subtract one array from another. You can however, subtract one element from another element.

So for that line, I believe you want something like this:

```
K = math.max(math.abs(array.get(High, bar) - array.get(Close1, bar)), math.abs(array.get(Low, bar) - array.get(Close1, bar)))
```

With `array.get()`, you can get value the of the element at the specified index.

You should fix this in all other occurences.

Comment: Thank you, very much, @BarisYakut. That's where my mistake was. I really appreciate your help.